# How to upload a object to GCP Cloud storage bucket using Config Connector or Create a Cloud Function with local source code file?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, gcp-config-connector

I am trying to deploy a Cloud-Function using [config connector](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/overview) in GCP.

Referring [CloudFunctionsFunction](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/cloudfunctions/cloudfunctionsfunction).

I have source code for the functions developed locally, using which the function should be created.

According to the above documentation, it accepts either `cloud storage url` or `source repository URL`

This can be done manually by adding the files to either source repo or cloud storage. But I want all the deployment to be automated using KCC.

**Actual Question:**
Is there any way I can automate the source code upload to bucket or source repo using KCC or pass the source code while creating the cloud-function itself as a field value.

I referred the docs present at:
[CloudFunctionsFunction](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/cloudfunctions/cloudfunctionsfunction)
[StorageBucket](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/storage/storagebucket)

**Expectation**
No manual efforts should be there while deploying the cloudfunction in GCP using [KCC](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs)

Answer (score 0):

As of the moment, there's no option to automate uploading the source code using either KCC or Config Connector.

In comparison to a Cloud Function that is deployed through Cloud SDK, permits deploying a function from source code located on your local machine.

You may want to file this one as a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so that it would be available in future updates. We don't have a specific ETA on this one however you can keep track of its progress once the ticket has been created.